# How to input an arrow before a node in Tikz

Tags: latex, tikz

Im currently using Tikz to cite a mathematical model from a research but I don't know how to input an arrow before the node.

Here's a photo of the mathematical model that I'm trying to code:

[image]

I don't know how to input the arrow entering the node F with dr above. Currently, this is all i have

```
\tikzstyle{Box} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=1.25cm, 
minimum height=1.25cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, fill=yellow!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{center}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node (F) [Box,  label=above:{\textcolor{red}{$I_1$}}] {$F$};
        \ 
        \node (D) [Box, right of =S, label=above:{\textcolor{red}{$I_2$}}] {$D$};
        \ 
        \node (W) [Box, right of =D, label=above:{\textcolor{red}{$I_3$}}] {$W$};
        \ 
        \node (R) [Box, right of =W, label=above:{\textcolor{red}{$I_4$}}] {$R$};

\draw [arrow] (F) -- node[above]{\textcolor{red}{$\varphi_1$}}(D);
\draw [arrow] (D) -- node[above]{\textcolor{red}{$\varphi_2$}}(W);
\draw [arrow] (W) -- node[above]{\textcolor{red}{$\varphi_3$}}(R);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{center}
```

I hope anyone can help me resolve this problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please always make a compilable [mre], not just code fragments. Please also note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty node "left of" your first box and then draw the arrow just like you do for your other arrows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  Box/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    minimum width=1.25cm, 
    minimum height=1.25cm,
    text centered, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=yellow!30
  },
  arrow/.style={
    thick,
    ->,
    >=stealth
  }
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node (F) [Box,  label=above:{\textcolor{red}{$I_1$}}] {$F$};
  \node (D) [Box, right of =F, label=above:{\textcolor{red}{$I_2$}}] {$D$};
  \node (W) [Box, right of =D, label=above:{\textcolor{red}{$I_3$}}] {$W$};
  \node (R) [Box, right of =W, label=above:{\textcolor{red}{$I_4$}}] {$R$};
  \node (foo) [left of=F] {};
  \draw [arrow] (F) -- node[above]{\textcolor{red}{$\varphi_1$}}(D);
  \draw [arrow] (D) -- node[above]{\textcolor{red}{$\varphi_2$}}(W);
  \draw [arrow] (W) -- node[above]{\textcolor{red}{$\varphi_3$}}(R);
  \draw [arrow] (foo) -- node[above]{\textcolor{red}{dr}}(F);        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I already did it and it solved my problem. Have a good day!